# How to manually trigger Spring validation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

The annotated Spring validation on fields of a POJO works when it is created from JSON request body. However, when I create the same object manually (using setters) and want to trigger validation, I'm not sure how to do that.

Here is the `Registration` class, which has `Builder` inner class that can build the object. In the `build()` method I would like to trigger Spring validation. Please scroll to the bottom and check `Builder.build()` and `Builder.validate()` methods to see current implementation. I'm using `javax.validation.Validator` to trigger validation, but I prefer to leverage Spring validation if possible.

```
package com.projcore.dao;

import com.projcore.util.ToString;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * The data transfer object that contains the information of a Registration
 * and validation rules for attributes.
 */
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public final class Registration {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Registration.class);

    private String id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String messageId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String version;

    @Size(max = 255)
    private String system;

    public Registration() {
    }

    private Registration(Builder builder) {
        this.id = builder.id;
        this.messageId = builder.messageId;
        this.version = builder.version;
        this.system = builder.system;
    }

    public static Builder getBuilder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getSystem() {
        return system;
    }

    public void setSystem(String system) {
        this.system = system;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToString.create(this);
    }

    /**
     * Builder pattern makes the object easier to construct in one line.
     */
    public static class Builder {

        private String id;

        private String messageId;

        private String version;

        private String system;

        private Builder() {}

        public Builder id(String id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder messageId(String messageId) {
            this.messageId = messageId;
            return this;
        }


        public Builder version(String version) {
            this.version = version;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder system(String system) {
            this.system = system;
            return this;
        }

        public Registration build() {
            Registration entry = new Registration(this);
        
            // *** Would like to trigger Spring validation here ***
            Set violations = validate(entry);
            if (violations.isEmpty())
                return entry;
            else
                throw new RuntimeException(violations.toString());
        }
    
        private Set validate(Registration entry) {
            Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
            Set<ConstraintViolation<Registration>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(entry);
            return constraintViolations;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Validation works fine here:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
Registration create(@RequestBody @Valid Registration registration)
```

---

## Solution:

Removed `Registraion.Builder.validate()`. Updated `Registraion.Builder.build()` to:

```
public Registration build() {
    Registration entry = new Registration(this);
    return (Registration) ValidatorUtil.validate(entry);
}
```

*ValidatorUtil.java*

```
package projcore.util;

import com.ericsson.admcore.error.InvalidDataException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter;

import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import java.util.Set;

public class ValidatorUtil {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ValidatorUtil.class);
    private static final Validator javaxValidator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    private static final SpringValidatorAdapter validator = new SpringValidatorAdapter(javaxValidator);

    public static Object validate(Object entry) {
        Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(entry, entry.getClass().getName());
        validator.validate(entry, errors);
        if (errors == null || errors.getAllErrors().isEmpty())
            return entry;
        else {
            LOGGER.error(errors.toString());
            throw new InvalidDataException(errors.getAllErrors().toString(), errors);
        }
    }
}
```

*InvalidDataException.java*

```
package projcore.error;

import org.springframework.validation.Errors;

/**
 * This exception is thrown when the dao has invalid data.
 */
public class InvalidDataException extends RuntimeException {

    private Errors errors;

    public InvalidDataException(String msg, Errors errors) {
        super(msg);
        setErrors(errors);
    }

    public Errors getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    public void setErrors(Errors errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Spring provides full support for the [JSR-303](https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/) Bean Validation API. This includes convenient support for bootstrapping a JSR-303 implementation as a Spring bean. This allows a `javax.validation.Validator` to be injected wherever validation is needed in your application.

Use the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` to configure a default JSR-303 Validator as a Spring bean:

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
```

The basic configuration above will trigger JSR-303 to initialize using its default bootstrap mechanism. A JSR-303 provider, such as Hibernate Validator, is expected to be present in the classpath and will be detected automatically.

### 5.7.2.1 Injecting a Validator

`LocalValidatorFactoryBean` implements both `javax.validation.Validator` and `org.springframework.validation.Validator`. You may inject a reference to one of these two interfaces into beans that need to invoke validation logic.

Inject a reference to `javax.validation.Validator` if you prefer to work with the JSR-303 API directly:

```
// JSR-303 Validator
import javax.validation.Validator;

@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

}
```

Inject a reference to `org.springframework.validation.Validator` if your bean requires the Spring Validation API:

```
// Spring Validator
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

}
```

Here is a well exaplained example:
[Using JSR 303 with "classic" Spring Validators (enter the SpringValidatorAdapter)](http://nonrepeatable.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-jsr-303-with-classic-spring.html)

> This link is very helpful. Wrapping javax.validation.Validator in
> org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter
> helped deal with errors consistently. Can you add this as an answer so
> that I can accept it

and
[Spring doc here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/reference/validation.html).

Comment: I think that Spring Boot also provides that Validator bean for you (not that it's hard to do yourself).

Comment: Does this mean spring validator can be used only in a @Service class to trigger validation? I have done enough reading online, so have seen examples like this, but I still don't understand how I can do it within the POJO, hence the question. I also know how to trigger validation for the custom validator, but not how to trigger default validation within a POJO. If possible, can you provide specific answer within the context of what I have.

Comment: You can inject the Validator to any spring bean.  there is an old example here http://nonrepeatable.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-jsr-303-with-classic-spring.html . comment here if you still have concerns

Comment: This link is very helpful. Wrapping javax.validation.Validator in org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter helped deal with errors consistently. Can you add this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I have edited this answer to include the link, so you can just accept this, and am glad that I can help

Comment: Ok I have a validator, I can validate. But what should I do with validation result? How can I convert it to some sort of exception that I can throw to end up with exactly the same result as when spring doing validation through `@Validated` annotation on controller's parameter? I understand that I can do this manually, manually serialize to json etc, but shouldn't it be easier way? Just way to mimic a behaviour of validation through annotation, but programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure it behaves like validation on fields of a POJO (exception, messages) you can use [DataBinder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html)

```java
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

@RestController
class Controller {

  @Autowired
  private Validator validator;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  Registration create() {
    Registration registration = Registraction.getBuilder()....build();
    DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(registration);
    binder.setValidator(validator);
    binder.validate();
    if (binder.getBindingResult().hasErrors()) {
      Method method = this.getClass().getMethod("create");
      MethodParameter methodParameter = new MethodParameter(method, 0);
      throw new MethodArgumentNotValidException(methodParameter, binder.getBindingResult());
    }
    return someService.create(registration);
  }

}
```