# Grails 3: Programatically call constraint validation methods

Tags: validation, grails

How can I access the pre-built constraint validations in Grails?

Lets say, for example, I want to use the `range` validator on a `Map` Object

```
Map<String, Double> myData

static constraints = {
   myData validator: { val, obj, errors ->
       //Iterate through all Double values and validate using `range` constraint
   }
}
```

It doesn't seem to make sense to have to write my own `range` validation method since Grails already has one built-in, somewhere.  How can I access it?

Just to clarify, `range` constraint is just an example.  Just looking for how to access any of those pre-builts in general.

**Update:**

To clarify with a simpler example.  I know how to use the constraints in the standard way.  I am trying to use the constraint validations programmatically which I cannot find documentation for.

```
def myMethod() {
    int myInt = 5;

    //HOW DO I CALL RANGE (OR ANY) OF THE PRE-BUILT VALIDATION METHODS
    if(RANGE(myInt, 0..5)) {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

Like i said, I don't want to reinvent the wheel if it's already there.  The API that the validation constraints use must be somewhere, how can I manually call those API's?

Comment: http://docs.grails.org/3.2.7/ref/Constraints/Usage.html listed here on RHS quick reference bar

Comment: did domainInstance.validate() not work?

Comment: @Vahid Sorry for not being clear.  I know how to use constraints as per the docs.  I am looking to use the validation methods outside the constraints.  Please see updated question.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you are trying to do Grails validation simply extends java validation and in short if you can do it in Java then so should it be possible in  groovy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702809/how-to-manually-trigger-spring-validation. Basically what your best bet I think for your scenario is to create a Validation bean like https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuemail-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugin/queuemail/validation/EmailQueueBean.groovy. Then let the bean call the validation methods like bean.validate() in your method

Comment: Sorry I hope it don't confuse you even more, so typically you would bind the bean with the data before passing into service https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuemail-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/services/org/grails/plugin/queuemail/QueueMailApiService.groovy#L243 - you could do all its validation in the controller - the controller auto magically binds received params to a validation bean - you would need to follow some of my controllers in the most recent plugins to see how it works - or in the service `MyBean bean = new MyBean(); bean.myInt=5; if (bean.validate()) { //do something}`

Answer (score 0):

`myDate range: 18..65 //could be age of a person for example`

Taken from: http://docs.grails.org/3.2.7/ref/Constraints/range.html

Comment: Sorry that is not what I'm asking.  I know how to use constraints as per the docs.  Please see updated question.

Comment: That is Spring under the hood so it’s validation framework should give you this functionality. When it comes to grails, i don’t know how to use utilize it in the way you need.