# Spring Validation without @Valid in Controller's handler methods and without implementing Validator interface?

Tags: java, spring

I have a model with a field annotated with `@NotNull`

```
public class Employee {
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    //other fields and getters/setters
}
```

But I don't have controllers. All I want to do is invoke validation on `Employee` model either when this method is invoked (this method is in a class that's a Spring component), or manual validation.

When using controllers, I could have annotation handler method with `@Valid Employee emp` followed by `BindingResults`. But I don't have controllers.

Or in some scenarios, I could have implemented `Validator` interface, And then used a combination of `BeanPropertyBindingResult` and `ValidationUtils.invokeValidator`. But again, in this case, That `@NotNull` on model `Employee` would not be invoked unless I add validation for it in `Validator` implementation.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution posted by [this guy.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28702809/4828463) Use this in the method:

```
javax.validation.Validator javaxValidator = javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter validator = new org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter(javaxValidator);

org.springframework.validation.Errors errors = new org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult.BeanPropertyBindingResult(objectThatNeedsToBeValidated, objectThatNeedsToBeValidated.getClass().getName());
validator.validate(objectThatNeedsToBeValidated, errors);
```

Edit: [This is better than the above solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28704025/4828463)